# How do I know which .dll is missing in python with cx_freeze?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy, cx-freeze

I have a project which I am packaging with cx_freeze. When I try to run the resulting exe I get an `ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.`

Here is my setup.py:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need
# fine tuning.
buildOptions = dict(build_exe='liquidation', packages=['scipy', 'numpy'], excludes=['scipy.spatial.cKDTree'],
                    includes=['scipy', 'numpy', 'numpy.core._methods', 'scipy.sparse.csgraph._validation',
                              'numpy.lib.format', 'numpy.linalg._umath_linalg', 'scipy.sparse._csparsetools',
                              'scipy.sparse.linalg.isolve._iterative', 'scipy.sparse.linalg.eigen.arpack._arpack',
                              'scipy.special._ufuncs_cxx', 'scipy.special.specfun', 'scipy.integrate._odepack',
                              'scipy.integrate._quadpack', 'scipy.integrate.vode', 'scipy.integrate._dop',
                              'scipy.integrate.lsoda', 'scipy.optimize._minpack', 'scipy.optimize._zeros',
                              'scipy.spatial', 'scipy.spatial.ckdtree', 'scipy.spatial.kdtree',
                              'scipy._distributor_init', 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'])

base = 'Console'

executables = [
    Executable('liquidation.py', base=base, targetName='liquidation.exe')
]

setup(name='liquidation',
      version='2.0',
      description='Program to run and test Liquidation algorithms',
      options=dict(build_exe=buildOptions),
      executables=executables)
```

When I run `python setup.py build_exe` it seems to complete successfully, but when I run the exe I get the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tamar\PycharmProjects\liquidation\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
  File "C:\Users\tamar\PycharmProjects\liquidation\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\multiarray.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import overrides
  File "C:\Users\tamar\PycharmProjects\liquidation\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\overrides.py", line 7, in <module>
    from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tamar\PycharmProjects\liquidation\venv\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\__startup__.py", line 40, in run
    module.run()
  File "C:\Users\tamar\PycharmProjects\liquidation\venv\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 37, in run
    exec(code, {'__name__': '__main__'})
  File "liquidation.py", line 64, in <module>
    from io_tools.stock_wrapper import StockWrapper
  File "C:\Users\tamar\PycharmProjects\liquidation\io_tools\stock_wrapper.py", line 4, in <module>
    from io_tools.io_helper import *
  File "C:\Users\tamar\PycharmProjects\liquidation\io_tools\io_helper.py", line 7, in <module>
    from numpy import float_
  File "C:\Users\tamar\PycharmProjects\liquidation\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "C:\Users\tamar\PycharmProjects\liquidation\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 54, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError:

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy c-extensions failed.
- Try uninstalling and reinstalling numpy.
- If you have already done that, then:
  1. Check that you expected to use Python3.7 from "C:\Users\tamar\PycharmProjects\liquidation\liquidation\liquidation.exe",
     and that you have no directories in your PATH or PYTHONPATH that can
     interfere with the Python and numpy version "1.18.3" you're trying to use.
  2. If (1) looks fine, you can open a new issue at
     https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues.  Please include details on:
     - how you installed Python
     - how you installed numpy
     - your operating system
     - whether or not you have multiple versions of Python installed
     - if you built from source, your compiler versions and ideally a build log

- If you're working with a numpy git repository, try `git clean -xdf`
  (removes all files not under version control) and rebuild numpy.

Note: this error has many possible causes, so please don't comment on
an existing issue about this - open a new one instead.

Original error was: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I understand that I need to point cx_freeze to the missing DLL's (either by adding them to `buildOptions.include_files` or by actually copying the DLL's to the build folder) but I am at a loss as to how to know which DLL's I am missing. `numpy.core._multiarray_umath` is in the build folder so I don't know what it could be.

I believe I am using the latest versions of numpy (1.18.3), scipy (1.4.1) and cx-freeze (6.1). Any help would be much appreciated!

**Update:** I used Dependency Walker to try and see what I am missing and it listed a file by the name of `LIBOPENBLAS.SVHFG5YE3RK3Z27NVFUDAPL2O3W6IMXW.GFORTRAN-WIN32.DLL` which cannot be found. All of the other dependencies have been copied into the build so it makes sense that this would be the missing one. Does anyone know where I can find this file?

Comment: did you try including the `openblas` as a library in your setup and see if that fixes it?

Comment: did you manage to correct this? I have the same issue here. Thanks.